# How would I emulate the xcopy command in Perl?

Tags: perl, batch-file, xcopy

Perl is a new language to me. I've been writing batch files. I have a script that I wrote as a batch file that I am trying to convert to Perl. This is my batch file:

```
    @echo off
    :LOOP
    echo File Copy Started 
    xcopy /s /Y  "Source" "Destination"
    echo File Copy Completed 
    TIMEOUT /T 80
    goto :LOOP
```

So I"m trying figure out if there is a command similar to xcopy in Perl or if I would need to figure out some other way to create the same function in Pearl. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: `xcopy` is thousands and thousands of lines long. We're not going to post that even though we can do something roughly similar is much less. (It probably wouldn't handle attributes permissions as well as `xcopy`, for starters.) You'd need to get the list of files, perhaps using [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule), then copy them, perhaps using [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Copy)

Comment: Are you asking for the equivalent of the program you actually posted (the batch file), perhaps?

Comment: `xcopy /s` without `/e` is weird.

Comment: No I'm not looking for the equivalent of the program I'm just looking for a starting place to emulate the xcopy function. I"m very new to using Perl. I'm used to Batch files. Thanks ikegami I will do some research on File::Fine::Rule and File::Copy. : ) I think that may help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I recursively copy the contents of directory using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117948/how-can-i-recursively-copy-the-contents-of-directory-using-perl)

Comment: And as the [top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1117953/1895394) recommends in that question - look at [File::Copy::Recursive](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ikegami notes in the comments, there is no single Perl command to do what [`xcopy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY) does.  While you *could* write some code to reimplement recursive file copying in Perl (e.g. using [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind) or [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule) and [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aCopy) as suggested), a simpler solution may be to just invoke `xcopy` from Perl using [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

```
system qw(xcopy /s /Y), $source, $destination;
```

**Edit:** Or just use [File::Copy::Recursive](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aCopy%3a%3aRecursive) from CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

There is this,

- [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html)
- [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule)

You could use those to implement it yourself, however being new to a language this might be of use:

```
system qw(xcopy /s /Y), $source, $destination;
```

However if you are writing performance-optimized code you shouldn't use this.